# Scala - combinator parser incorrect - repsep

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I am trying to create a simple parser as below. However, I am not sure why combinator parser is complaining on not recognizing 'floatingPointNumber' when there are 'dates' format. It recognizes when it is 'ident'

Below is the code with error.

Many thanks for help!

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers

class MyParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def dates = repsep(date, ";")
  def date = """\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}""".r
  def value = ident | dates | date | floatingPointNumber
  def obj = "("~>repsep(value,",")<~")"
}
object MyParser extends MyParser { 
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {   
    println(parseAll(obj, "(22-Jan-2016;09-Mar-2015)"))
    println(parseAll(obj, "(22-Jan-2016;09-Mar-2015,blah3)"))
    println(parseAll(obj, "(22-Jan-2016;09-Mar-2015,32)"))
  }
}

[1.26] parsed: List(List(22-Jan-2016, 09-Mar-2015))
[1.32] parsed: List(List(22-Jan-2016, 09-Mar-2015), blah3)
[1.26] failure: `)' expected but `3' found
(22-Jan-2016;09-Mar-2015,32)
                         ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want *at least one* `date` to be present in `dates`, using

```
def dates = rep1sep(date, ";")
```

seems to fix the problem.

I believe the reason is that the `dates` parser is able to accept an empty string (i.e. "" would parse as `Nil`), and that causes the `floatingPointNumber` part of the `value` parser to never be evaluated. If you change `dates` so it cannot accept an empty input, the parse succeeds:

```
def fixedDates = rep1sep(date, ";")
def fixedValue = ident | fixedDates | date | floatingPointNumber
def fixedObj = "("~>repsep(fixedValue,",")<~")"

parseAll(fixedObj, "(22-Jan-2016;09-Mar-2015,32)")
// MyParser.ParseResult[List[Object]] = 
// [1.29] parsed: List(List(22-Jan-2016, 09-Mar-2015), 32)
```

Comment: Thanks, miss the subtlety of at least one!